# pycave kmeans-gpu disable model trainer outputs from being printed

Tags: pytorch-lightning

This is a code snippet to run KMeans using GPU.

Documentation-link:https://pycave.borchero.com/sites/generated/clustering/kmeans/pycave.clustering.KMeans.html

```
import torch
from pycave.clustering import KMeans

X = torch.cat([
    torch.randn(1000, 6) - 5,
    torch.randn(1000, 6),
    torch.randn(1000, 6) + 5,
])

estimator = KMeans(num_clusters = 3, trainer_params=dict(gpus=1, 
                                                         enable_progress_bar=0, 
                                                         max_epochs=100,))
labels = estimator.fit_predict(X).numpy()

pd.value_counts(labels)
```

The issue is with how to disable the console output from the estimator.

Current Output:

```
Running initialization...

{'batch_size': 3000, 'collate_fn': <function collate_tensor at 0x000002BE21221700>}

Fitting K-Means...

{'batch_size': 3000, 'collate_fn': <function collate_tensor at 0x000002BE21221700>}
{'batch_size': 1, 'sampler': None, 'batch_sampler': <pytorch_lightning.overrides.distributed.IndexBatchSamplerWrapper object at 0x000002BE593A55B0>, 'collate_fn': <function collate_tensor at 0x000002BE21221700>, 'shuffle': False, 'drop_last': False}

0    1000
2    1000
1    1000
dtype: int64
```

Expected Output:

```
0    1000
2    1000
1    1000
dtype: int64
```

*Info regarding trainer_params parameter

(Optional[Dict[str, Any]]) --
Initialization parameters to use when initializing a PyTorch Lightning trainer. By default, it disables various stdout logs unless PyCave is configured to do verbose logging. Checkpointing and logging are disabled regardless of the log level.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionaries that are printed should never be there, that's a bug in a dependency. Resolved in the latest build.

As far as the PyCave logs are concerned (Running initialization... and Fitting K-Means...), you can turn them off easily by adding the following:

```
import logging
from pycave import set_logging_level

set_logging_level(logging.WARNING)
```

Note that set_logging_level(logging.WARNING) also turns off the progress bar and the model summary automatically so you don't have to set these flags explicitly.